Execute multiple commands in remote machines at once
My execution on multiple remote computers as follows.

Kill Java process
Copy files to specific location
Run application specific batch

Below script works as expected. How can I run it in parallel. Also, pskill64 establishing connection each time when it executes. It takes time to complete above mentioned steps.
Below script works in sequential mode. How can we run on multiple remote machines at a time?
 @echo off
 set uname=domain\\admin
 set pword=
 FOR /F "tokens=\* delims=" %%i in (**list1**.txt) DO (
    pskill64 \\%%i -u %uname% -p %pword% java.exe
    pskill64 \\%%i -u %uname% -p %pword% javaw.exe
    pskill64 \\%%i -u %uname% -p %pword% edge.exe
    xcopy \\%%i\\C$\\Users\\tcserv\\Downloads\\PSTools\\fileToBeCopied.txt               \\%%i\\D$\\APP\\APPRoot\\Runtime
    NET USE \\%%i\\D$\\TC143\\TR\\portal /u:%uname% %pword%
    psexec64 \\%%i "D:\\APP\\APPRoot\\Runtime\\register.bat" 
)


Traditionally you'd use software like Ansible for this

[untested - theoretical only]
 @echo off
 set "uname=domain\\admin"
 set "pword="
 FOR /F "tokens=\* delims=" %%i in (**list1**.txt) DO start "%%i" secondbatch "%%i" "%uname%" "%pword%"

[secondbatch.bat]
 @echo off
 pskill64 \\%~1 -u %~2 -p %~3 java.exe
 pskill64 \\%~1 -u %~2 -p %~3 javaw.exe
 pskill64 \\%~1 -u %~2 -p %~3 edge.exe
 xcopy \\%~1\\C$\\Users\tcserv\\Downloads\\PSTools\fileToBeCopied.txt \\%~1\\D$\\APP\\APPRoot\\Runtime
 NET USE \\%~1\\D$\\TC143\\TR\\portal /u:%~2 %~3
 psexec64 \\%~1 "D:\\APP\\APPRoot\\Runtime\\register.bat"
 goto :eof

